# why all previous commits got pushed again to the new branch?

Tags: git, gitlab, push, git-commit

I pushed some commits to branch A, and create a new branch B, pushed some other commits to B, why commits which were pushed to A also got pushed to B?

I tried to make changes directly on GitHub, but once I use VSCode to push, all previous commits got pushed again.

Comment: How did you create branch B?

Comment: A branch is nothing more than a pointer to a commit. A commit points to its parent(s). If commits reachable from A are reachable from B too, they will be pushed.

Comment: Small correction: they will not be _pushed again_, since they were already pushed when branch A was pushed. But they are "part of B".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate ^main A B`

Comment: @RomainValeri create from main branch

Comment: @YuxuanZhang Emphasis on **How**. Can you show us the command, and also a bit of prior context to see where `HEAD` was when you created the branch.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the exact sequence of commands, which you executed to create both branches, too

Answer (score 2):

When you create your branch B, from your branch A, the commits you pushed before are already in the branch. If you wanted to create a separate branch without those commits, you must have checkout the commit before the branch A, and make a branch from this commit.

Comment: but both A and B are created from main branch

Comment: But you were _on `branchA`_  when you created `branchB`. If you wanted the branch to be created from `main`, you should have checked out that branch before creating `branchB`  or specified it: `git checkout -b branchB main`. If you do not specify from what point you want to start your new branch from, the current branch/commit is used.